# how to use an if else statement with a spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

this is my code I don't know how to use if else statement with two spinner
//(spinner1.equals"THB" && spinner2.equals"USD") <--something like that

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e_TbY6e-KAE7Iq6GLq2CFy9WA1VBy1qx/view?fbclid=IwAR1s7C9SVm2S202uAmURjwTilHu2ppwkHclvN7gDT3cEFFwZkqyktZv6MRE

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). **You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: Post your code here, nobody will download a zip file and search for the relevant part of your code.

Comment: like what @f1sh said. we need to see your code. Nobody like their computer infected with malware.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the values of the spinner that the user has chosen:

```
Spinner spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.your_spinner1);
Spinner spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.your_spinner2);

if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("THB") && spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("USD"){

    //do stuff here

}
```

Like the user f1sh in the comment said, post your code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Extend an interface **AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener**

```
package com.example.acer.spinner;

import android.accessibilityservice.GestureDescription;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spn,spn1;
    EditText inmoney;
    TextView answer;
    Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    inmoney=findViewById(R.id.text);
    answer=findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btn=findViewById(R.id.button);

    // first spinner
    spn=findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spn1=findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    String [] legion ={"THB","USD","EUR","JPY","SGD","MYN","CNY"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,legion);
    spn.setAdapter(adapter);
    spn1.setAdapter(adapter);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            exrate();
        }
    });
}
public void exrate(){
    double num=Double.parseDouble(inmoney.getText().toString());
    if (spn1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("THB") && spn.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("USD")){
        double ans=num*5;
        answer.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
    }
    else{
        //do other currency conversions
    }
}
}
```

You can also use ***else if(condition) instead of just else, to do other comparison and conversions***

**It is called as Ladder-if in Java jargon**